# MASM32 - fatal error A1010: unmatched block nesting : CDSEG

Tags: assembly, masm32

```
DTSEG SEGMENT
DATAW DW 97F4H
COUNT DB 0
CNT_ASC DB 2 DUP(0), '$'
DTSEG ENDS

CDSEG SEGMENT
START:
ASSUME  CS:CDSEG, DS:DTSEG
MOV AX, DTSEG
MOV DS, AX
SUB AL, AL
MOV DL, 16
MOV BX, DATAW
AGAIN:  ROL BX, 1
JNC NEXT
ADD AL, 1
DAA
NEXT:   DEC DL
JNZ AGAIN
MOV COUNT, AL
CALL BCD2ASC
CALL DISPLAY
MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
END START

BCD2ASC PROC
MOV AL, COUNT
MOV AH, AL
AND AX, 0F00FH
MOV CL, 4
SHR AH, CL
OR AX, 3030H
XCHG AH, AL
MOV CNT_ASC, AX
RET
BCD2ASC ENDP

DISPLAY PROC
MOV AH, 09
MOV DX, OFFSET CNT_ASC
INT 21H
RET
DISPLAY ENDP
```

This code is 'count the number of 1 contained in integer word'.
I think '97F4H' is integer word and COUNT is the number of 1.
There is an error in the last line. I don't know how to fix this code.
I don't know where to put 'CDSEG ENDP'.
I use this program for the first time.
Please help~

Comment: I append 'CDSEG ENDS' after DISPLAY ENDP, but there is an error(END directive required at end of file). There is another error in MOV AX, DTSEG(symbol type conflict). How can I fix it?

Comment: You place `END START` at the end of the file, not in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Put `CDSEG ENDP` after the last line of the file, because everything after `CDSEG SEGMENT` is instructions.  You want them to be part of the code segment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Post that as an answer and I'll delete this.  I only posted as an answer instead of comment in reply to the OP's *I don't know where to put 'CDSEG ENDP'.*, but it makes sense now that they'd still be asking this question if they were trying the wrong directive.